# How to wait for a response from the client while making a request?

Tags: node.js, express

This is the flow:

1. I send a request to my server: `GET /status/`
2. My server sends a push notification to my client
3. My client - after a slight delay(up to 10
   seconds) - makes a request to my server with the status: `POST
   /status/XYZ`
4. Now the request i started on step 1, should return XYZ

My server is node.js and i'm using express for routing. Any ideas how can i achieve something like this? My idea was to store the status in my database in step 3, and query my db every second in step 1 until i have the status, but i'm pretty sure this is not a good solution.

Comment: Instead of polling can't you use events or notification.

Comment: If the inner-request is asynchronous than things get messy. You could maybe keep the outer-request in some in-memory data structure and if the inner-requests answer comes in answer all those requests?

Comment: Hi @passatgt if any of the answers has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status in real time? You should use sockets for that. Have a look at [socket.io](http://socket.io/)

Still want to use HTTP(s) requests?

Simply store the result of the first request into an object inside (or outside) the database (it would act as a cache layer). So when he queries he can get that result straight away. Something like:

```
{
 ABC: value
 XYZ: value,
}
```

```
router.post('status/XYZ', (req, res) => {
  return res.json(values['XYZ']);
});
```